# How to read a text file with ACE library

Tags: ace

What is the easiest way to read a text file into an ACE_TCHAR* (or ACE_TString) ? is it possible to read a file with ACE_OS::read() or ACE_OS::fread()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular `ACE_OS::read()`, see `ACE_wrappers/examples/APG/Processes/Spawn.cpp`, operation `dumpRun()`